Is there an A*/D* variant for graph where path to destination is unraveled based on whether it's closer to the destination?
I have a few constraints in my path finding application for source to destination routing on a map:

Server has a huge map and Client can only query a small chunk of it at a time because of data transfer and server processing time limits.
Full map is too big to send directly to the client and Server is very slow to send larger chunks because it's doing some cryptographic operations on them.
Chunks queried should be as few as possible because of above.
An assumption that client can get chunk(s) which has the source node and the destination node. But not the regions that might lie on the path necessarily.
Client has to find out (e.g. with A*) whether it can reach the destination from source given the chunks of the map it has. It can query for missing/necessary chunks any time.

Given these constraints, are there any algorithms that can figure out which chunks exactly to pull from the server?
I thought of one approach where I can use precomputed landmark heuristic to make a good guess but the size of this heuristic is very very large (even bigger than my map) and it doesn't work well with the constraints I have above.
I came across D* and it seems like a good fit but only issue is that the algorithm by itself doesn't determine the ideal chunk to pull from the server. Are there any variations on D*/A* which takes that into consideration? i.e. not just calculating shortest path on a dynamic graph but also determining which parts of the full graph to pull.

Knowing how chunks are connected and the cost to get from one chunk to another, you could run A* or D* on the graph of the chunks. It would even tell you (approximately or precisely) which chunks are in the open set to fetch next. Actually, since the cost to get through a chunk is different depending on where you start and finish, you might use the graph of chunk edges.

Thank you! Yes I think this might be one way to do it. Will try and see if it's feasible
